# Angular application loading weirdly when I add "/" at the end of URL

Tags: angular, typescript, search, cloudflare

I am having an issue. It just published my first project and now I am realising if you add an "/" to the end of the URL it does load in a very different way I cant even explain. When you add a "Trailingslash" some of the Buttons of the Website are not clickable and if I do this with ng serve the font is changing, I cant click buttons and I get a white border to the side. You can try it yourself on https://22ndspartans.de the issue is only on the discord page at https://22ndspartans.de/discord and the issues appear with https://22ndspartans.de/discord/.

I tried it on my localhost, I tried to do it with other browsers and other devices. I found this issue when I set up my google search indexing. When I clicked my Discord page directly from the search results it doesn't load any backgroundimage. At the begining the issue was on the other pages aswell. I am abolutely confused.
Sorry for the english I gave my best to explain it.
[you can see the white border and font here with Trailingslash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9NOF.jpg) ---->
[How it should be (without trailingslash)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Pmk.jpg)

Edit: I found out in the published version the Anchor to the homepage is not working when you have a trailingslash on any other page. The rest seems to be working. I am hosting with cloudflare. Maybe this has something to do with google search aswell. Idk

2nd Edit: Okay I found out that the main problem is the Trailingslash so how do I tell my application to redirect to no trailingslash if a trailingslash is called? Or how do I get my website to load correctly with Trailingslash

Updated code:
[HTML of DiscordComponent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJgZp.jpg)---->[TS of DiscordComponent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXYub.jpg)---->[New appo.routes.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW4S9.jpg)

Comment: There is no `<base href="/">` in the HTML and I guess you do not provide it with `APP_BASE_HREF` token?

Comment: I dont know what this is so no I dont think so. I just used the routerLink function. (for example: routerLink="discord")

Comment: Adding the trailing slash most likely done by web server, and you need to make your app to work properly with and without slash. The problem, most likely is missing  base href, hard to say for sure without seeing your setup.

Comment: Can you tell how to use Base href in Angular? Will this help: https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF ?

Comment: The easiest way is to put `<base href="/">` to your index html, not sure why you don't have one, the exact value depends on how your app is deployed and there may be some specific for the cloudflare.

Comment: If i am getting this right and tested it right it just forces the browser to load with the desired domain. But it just forced it into trailingslash what makes my problem worse.

Comment: Little correction: I think it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using standalone components you don't need in your routes any lazyloading, standalone it is already lazyLoading strategy.
Also, your homeComponent with `pash: ""` must be at first place, and you don't need this one with path: "home".
Make sure you are imported all necessary modules and components directly to your discordComponent due to your standalone strategy.

Comment: I added a code block for my new app.routes.ts and my discord html+ts. I also made sure my components were all loaded correctly. I am just using some Angular Material omponents on the subpages.

Comment: My subpages are Discord, Join and Gallery all having the same issue with Trailingslash. In the published version i cant click on the logo to go back to the main page and on the serve version it shows very weirdly (images on main thread) (If you want you can see it yourself on https://22ndspartans.de ) Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

Here are some potential causes and solutions:

1. **Angular Route Configuration**: Make sure that your route configuration is correctly set up to handle trailing slashes. You can do this by setting the `trailingSlash` option to `true` or `false` in your route configuration. For example:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
        trailingSlash: true // or false
      }
    ])
  ]
})
```

This will tell Angular to either add or remove the trailing slash from the URL.

See this blog on [trailing slash](https://dev.to/ayyash/fixing-the-trailing-slash-in-static-site-generation-107k).

2. **Server Configuration**: If you're using a server-side rendering (SSR) setup, your server configuration might be affecting the way Angular handles routes. Make sure that your server is configured to handle trailing slashes correctly. For example, if you're using Node.js and Express.js, you can use the `express-urlrewrite` package to rewrite URLs and remove trailing slashes.
3. **HTML Base Tag**: The `tag in your HTML header can also affect how Angular handles routes. Make sure that the` tag is set to the correct URL, including the trailing slash. For example:

4. **CSS and Layout Issues**: The issues with button clickability and font changes could be related to CSS and layout problems. Make sure that your CSS is correctly loaded and that there are no layout issues causing the buttons to become unclickable.
5. **ng serve**: When using `ng serve`, Angular uses a development server that can sometimes behave differently than a production environment. Try building your application with `ng build` and serving it with a production server to see if the issues persist.

Comment: I am using Angular 17 with standalone components and I dont have the trailingSlash option. 2. I am using cloudflare but I would like to resolve it within the application to not get the SEO confused 3. I think I didn't make a mistake here. 4. CSS loads correctly without trailingslash. 5. This is a point but the buttons are still not clickable in build.

Comment: In that case, have you tried to lazy-load routes? In the past, a lazy route pointed to an NgModule with child routes. As there are no NgModules anymore, loadChildren can now directly point to a lazy routing configuration.

Comment: I added an image on main post. Lazy loading didn't work